# How to split the string which is inside square brackets and put into an array using JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I am having a concatenated string `[Provider Name 2]-[124]-[12-3456790]`.

I want in

```
array[0] = "Provider Name 2", 
array[1] = 124, 
array[2] = "12-3456790"
```

I tried using string split with matches but it didn't work for me

Comment: This link will help you getting this in right way : https://www.sitepoint.com/trimming-strings-in-javascript/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression to match non-`[]` characters, and then lookahead for a `]`:

```js
const input = "[Provider Name 2]-[124]-[12-3456790]";
const output = input.match(/[^[\]]+(?=\])/g);
console.log(output);
```

`/[^[\]]+(?=\])/` means:

- `[^[\]]+` - Match one or more characters which are neither`[` nor `]`
- `(?=\])` - Check that the next character after the matched substring is a `]`

If you also need to be absolutely sure that the character that comes before the start of the match is a `[`, you can use lookbehind on newer environments:

```js
const input = "[Provider Name 2]-[124]-[12-3456790]";
const output = input.match(/(?<=\[)[^[\]]+(?=\])/g);
console.log(output);
```

If you can't use lookbehind, match the beginning square bracket instead, and then `.map` the array of matches to remove the first character afterwards:

```js
const input = "[Provider Name 2]-[124]-[12-3456790]";
const output = input.match(/\[[^[\]]+(?=\])/g)
  .map(str => str.slice(1));
console.log(output);
```